# GCP / shielded_vm_integrity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

after changing the size of a GCP VM, I can no longer connect in ssh and I have a shielded_vm_integrity type error.
Have you encountered this before?

Comment: That is not the way to ask a software development question. State the problem, error messages, and steps you have completed to solve the problem. Please read these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Updating the integrity policy baseline](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#updating-baseline)

Comment: I think the initial problem has been solved but I'm not able to tog on the VM using ssh. I'm using Google CLI, Putty, etc... and having a complete review for the whole conf but no way. I will closed this issue because it solve and request another one for SSH issue.

Comment: @jsagnon make sure you enable serial console https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console#enable_project_access 
  and use the serial console to t-shoot from that point, fell free to post a new question if you cannot find a way to make it work.

Comment: I'm able ton connect using serial port but the server is not in normal mode and nothing is working